# Automatic print pdf file on chrome or firefox (both lastest version) using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, browser, printing

I am doing a function to auto print the pdf file, the file is returned from the server.
It is currently showing a print window, but I want the file to be printed on the printer at all times without have to press the print button.

current:

[image: current]

I read a lot of articles on stackoverflow, and other pages but it's failed.

Please help me!
Thanks alot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem

In Chrome:

- step 1:

config run chrome silent printing on mode --kiosk-printing edit target on chrome shortcut properties
Ex:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk-printing "http://localhost:8080/this"

- step 2:

code

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframe.style.display = 'none';
            iframe.onload = function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    iframe.focus();
                    iframe.contentWindow.print();
                }, 0);
            };
            iframe.src = _blobUrl;
```

In Firefox:

- step1: config printing silent

goto about:config create new Boolean preference name="print.always_print_silent" Value=true

- step 2: code

  var myWindow = window.open(_blobUrl, '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
   myWindow.focus();
   myWindow.print();
   myWindow.close();